# How do I find the string between two special characters?

Tags: python, string, special-characters

For example, I need everything in between the two square brackets.
File1

```
[Home sapiens]
[Mus musculus 1]
[virus 1 [isolated from china]]
```

So considering the above example, I need everything in between the first and last square brackets.

Comment: So you want it to return `Home sapiens] [Mus musculus 1] [virus 1 [isolated from china]`?

Comment: No I want it to return, Homo sapiens, Mus musculus 1, virus 1[isolated from china]. Means everything except the first and last square bracket.

Comment: Well, the first square bracket is the one occurring just before "Home", and the last is the one after `china]`. Your proposed result is also missing the second, third, fourth, and fifth square brackets. Or do you mean everything but the first and last square bracket on each line? In which case, do you expect it to return one string, or a list of strings? Do you want `["Home sapiens", "Mus musculus 1", "virus 1 [isolated from china]"]`?

Comment: Thanks Kevin. You are right. It was not very clear. I mean everything but the first and last square bracket on each line.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Regular expressions are the most flexible option.

For another approach, you can try string's [partition](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) and [rpartition](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition) methods:

```
>>> s = "[virus 1 [isolated from china]]"
>>> s.partition('[')[-1].rpartition(']')[0]
'virus 1 [isolated from china]'
```

Comment: Be aware that this fails if the second character is missing: `'/test'.partition('/')[-1].rpartition('/')[0]` will not find "test", but `'/test/'.partition('/')[-1].rpartition('/')[0]` will.

Answer (score 20):

You can use a greedy regex:

```
re.search(r'\[(.*)\]', your_string).group(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Given your sample input, it looks like every line begins and ends with brackets. In which case, forget regexps, this is trivial:

```
for line in whatever:
    contents = line.strip()[1:-1]
```

(I've added the `strip` in case your line source is leaving the newlines in, or there are invisible spaces after the closing bracket in your input. If it's not necessary, leave it out.)