# Extract Parts of String from in Between Two Characters

Tags: python, string

If I have a string like this:

```
string = "12345|67891|23456|123456?"
```

how would I take out the "12345" and the "67891", etc (the characters between the pipes) and add them to a list all the way until the question mark (I am using the question mark in my code as a terminating character)?

A similar question has been asked here:
[How do I find the string between two special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716342/how-do-i-find-the-string-between-two-special-characters)

but I think mine is different because I need to do it multiple times in the same, one-line string.

Here is what I am hoping to achieve:

```
[PROGRAM BEGINS]
>>>string = "12345|67891|23456|123456?"
>>>string_list = []
>>>#some code to extract it and add it to a list called string_list
>>>print string_list
["12345","67891","23456","123456"]
[PROGRAM TERMINATES]
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You want to use the [split](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) function

Comment: Are you trying to extract only the digits or the `?` should be included as well?

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور only the digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the question mark:

```
>>> string = "12345|67891|23456|123456"
>>> string.split('|')
['12345', '67891', '23456', '123456']
>>>
```

Comment: Its says I have to wait nine minutes to mark this as correct...but I will. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I had the question mark because I thought I was going to need like a `for` loop or something.  XD

Answer (score 2):

If the question mark is always at the end.

```
>>> string = "12345|67891|23456|123456?"
>>> string.rstrip('?').split('|')
['12345', '67891', '23456', '123456']
```

regex are relatively slow for performing tasks like this

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to split on anything which is not a digit `\D`:

```
import re

matches = filter(None, re.split('\D', "12345|67891|23456|123456?"))
print matches # ['12345', '67891', '23456', '123456']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), this way:

```
>>>import re
>>>s = "12345|67891|23456|123456?"
>>>string_list = re.findall(r'\d+',s)
>>>string_list
['12345', '67891', '23456', '123456']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the split function. Str.split("|") and assign the result to an array variable.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are using '?' as a terminating char. The safest way to do this would be:

```
>>> string = "12345|67891|23456|123456?"
>>> string.split('?')[0].split('|')
['12345', '67891', '23456', '123456']
```